# How to show anything(e.g information) like popup according to cursor's place?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I want to show some information at textBox exactly at cursor's place.Not like in the intellisense at C# :it appears where "." inserted.Please help.At picture you see it appears according to dot(".") but i want to it appear according to that which i mentioned at picture(sorry my english is bad,and i couldnt find what that means .)

[image]

Comment: You are writing an app to do this or you want Visual Studio to do it?

Comment: its look like you want autocomplete textbox feature in wpf right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is, whenever the user presses a key inside the textbox, handle the OnKeyDown event, compute the current cursor position and repaint the popup control. This popup control can be defined by you as a custom control.

Edit: as jberger pointed out, you can also implement the handler for OnSelectionChanged, to handle any cursor change.

Comment: this would work for last character position, but may not always work "exactly at cursor's place". +1 for best possible.

Comment: Yes, you are right, there should be some other event to indicate the cursor position changing.

Comment: [TextBoxBase.OnSelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.onselectionchanged.aspx)

Comment: @jberger, thanks, I was aware of that event, but I didn't know it also fires when the caret position changes. Good to know. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Popup: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx

This is essentially a window without border displayed above other content.

Assign PlacementMode.Mouse to the property Placement. There are several other properties to modify the popup position.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use AdornerClass for creating your own custom-styled popup.
Check this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.documents.adorner.aspx
If you aren't used Adorner class yet, you can start with: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753340.aspx